# Sublinear algorithm for $\sum_{i = 1}^n i \cdot \varphi (i)$

Tags: number-theory, summation, algorithms, computer-science, totient-function

I am trying to evaluate the sum $\sum_{i = 1}^n i \cdot \varphi (i)$ for large values of $n$, and therefore I need a sublinear algorithm for this. The summation of the totient function alone $\sum_{i = 1}^n  \varphi (i)$ indeed has sublinear algorithms mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3207257/summing-the-totient-function-sum-k-1n-varphik). But the required sum here is different.

The progress I have made thus far is to show that $i \cdot \varphi (i) = \varphi(i^2)$ and therefore the sum may be rewritten (in perhaps a simpler form for summation):

$$\sum_{i = 1}^n i \cdot \varphi (i) = \sum_{i = 1}^n \varphi(i^2)$$

Is it possible to evaluate this sum in sublinear time?

Comment: @JeanMarie True, removed

Comment: Some things are overrated, everybody knows what $\varphi$ means. "Sublinear" is elementary, you can easily do $O(n^{3/4})$ time and $O(n^{1/2})$ space, or $O(n^{2/3+\epsilon})$ time and space. So... go ahead, it's your problem, after all!