# Complexity of recursion with floor division $f(N) = F(N) - \sum_{m=2}^N f \left(\left\lfloor\frac N m \right\rfloor\right)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, computational-complexity, recursive-algorithms, analysis-of-algorithms

Often in computational number theory, to compute $f(N)$, there are identities like

$$F(N) = \sum_{m=1}^N  f \left(\left\lfloor\frac N m \right\rfloor\right) $$

where $F(N)$ is easy to compute, i.e. $O(1)$ time, so can be rewritten (see [Efficient computation of $\sum_{k=1}^n \left\lfloor \frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384520/efficient-computation-of-sum-k-1n-left-lfloor-fracnk-right-rfloor?rq=1))

$$f(N) = F(N) - \sum_{m=2}^N  f \left(\left\lfloor\frac N m \right\rfloor\right)$$

There are more elaborate ways to rewrite, including using $\sqrt{N}$ as a cutoff for switching from computing $f(\lfloor N/m\rfloor)$ to iterating through $f(m)$, and pulling out even $m$ terms as $F(\lfloor N/2\rfloor)$.

What is the time complexity of computing $f(N)$ if all values are memoized?

For example, $f(100)$ depends on all the values of $\lfloor N/m \rfloor$, in this case $f(50), f(33), f(25), f(20), f(16), \dots, 50 \times f(1) $.

How can I analyze this? It's obvious we never need to call at least half of the $N$ values, $f(m)$ for $N/2 < m \le N$. The recursive calls depend on how many distinct $f(\lfloor N/m\rfloor)$ there are and their magnitudes. $a(N) = |\{\lfloor N/m \rfloor, 2 \le m \le N\}|$ doesn't seem to be on OEIS, unless I computed incorrectly.

```
[len(set([N//m for m in range(2, N+1)])) for N in range(2, 100)]
```

Comment: The more natural sequence is $a(N)+1 = |\{ \lfloor N/m \rfloor, 1 \le m \le N\} | $, which is https://oeis.org/A055086.  There is an exact formula given, $a(N) = \lfloor \sqrt{4n+1} \rfloor - 2$.

Comment: About $2 \sqrt N$ calls. If you pull out all even $m$ in the sum as $F(N//2)$, maybe it is $\sqrt N$ calls.

Comment: I believe if you go in decreasing order of $m$, then each recursive call only expands by one level, because the values needed to compute $f([N/a])$ look like $f([[N/a]/b])$ and $[[N/a]/b] = [N/(ab)]$ which has already been computed.  So the asymptotics there should be very easy to calculate.  For the forward order, the exact cost is not clear to me, though I'm willing to believe they're comparable.

Comment: Ok I suppose iterating m from 2 to N as written has to take linear time at least, which is counter to the motivation to find a sublinear algorithm. I'll look at the more elaborate recursions and modify the question.

Comment: I think the number of iterations can be made sublinear by iterating over $m$ more efficiently (for large values of $m$, namely values above $O(\sqrt N)$, one can iterate over the range rather than the domain).  E.g. you already know that $[N/m] = 1$ for all $m$ between $(N+1)/2$ and $N$, and these can all be grouped together without iterating through them one at a time.  Whether the *overall* recursion is sublinear, that I do not know.

Comment: Yes I've been working on updating an old answer of mine that goes through the hyperbola method. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1740370/122489

Comment: @ErickWong I think your reasoning is correct for f(n) computing only values that are used for f(N). If you can post as an answer that would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks.  Until I wrote it up I didn't realize how similar your old answer is to mine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my attempt at a version of this which seems to be easy to analyze.  If we reverse the order of the summation (largest values of $m$ first), then I claim that we never need to recurse beyond depth 1.  When we're expanding the summands of $f(\lfloor N/m\rfloor)$, those look like $f(\lfloor\lfloor N/m\rfloor / b \rfloor)$ for some $b>1$, but this is exactly equal to $\lfloor N/(mb)\rfloor$ which we have already calculated in an earlier step since $mb>m$.

We know (see comments on OP) that there are roughly $2\sqrt{N}$ distinct values of $m$, so it is helpful to group them into two types:

- when $m > \sqrt{N}$ then $\lfloor N/m\rfloor < \sqrt{N}$, so for each of the integer values from $r=1$ to $r\approx\sqrt{N}$ we can, in constant time, count how many distinct $m$ have $\lfloor N/m\rfloor = r$, and multiply it by the value of $f(r)$.
- when $1 < m \le \sqrt{N}$ we go back to iterating over $m$ (in descending order), and the logic above means there is no deeper recursion so we just need to sum the $2\sqrt{N/m}$ memoized terms to expand $f(\lfloor N/m\rfloor)$.

So the total number of evaluations-and-memoizations of $f$ needed looks like $\sqrt{N}$ for the first type, plus $\sum_{m=2}^\sqrt{N} 2\sqrt{N/m}$ for the second type, which should be approximated by the corresponding integral which evaluates to (I think) $4 N^{3/4}$, nicely sublinear.  And the memory footprint looks to be $O(\sqrt{N})$ as well.